# Cannot Get RazorView from Windsor Container using MVC 3 Beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, razor

This is how my Application_Start looks:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    _container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>()
        .Instance(_container),
        Component.For<IView, IViewPageActivator>()
            .ImplementedBy<RazorView>(),
        Component.For<IFilterProvider>()
            .ImplementedBy<WindsorFilterAttributeFilterProvider>(),
        Component.For<IControllerFactory>()
            .ImplementedBy<WindsorControllerFactory>(),
        Component.For<ControllerContext>()
            .ImplementedBy<ControllerContext>()
    );


    _container.Register(
        AllTypes.Of<IController>()
            .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
    );
```

Yet when trying to run the solution I get the following error:

```
Can't create component 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView' as it has dependencies to be
satisfied. 
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView is waiting for the following dependencies: 

Keys (components with specific keys)
- viewPath which was not registered. 
- layoutPath which was not registered. 
- runViewStartPages which was not registered. 
- viewStartFileExtensions which was not registered.
```

How do I setup the container such that it can get the required information dynamically at run time? As I assume at the very least viewPath will change for each Controller.

Comment: Why do you need a container for RazorView? Views were not designed to be extended a DI-like mechanism. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Simply I am trying to display a html page using the RazorView template engine. I was under the impression that it was the right thing / good thing to put the view engine in the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still playing around with MVC, but I think I can point you in the right direction.

When you registered the component for RazorView you want to use the DynamicParamters method - eg:

```
Component.For<IView>().ImplementedBy<RazorView>()
    .DynamicParameters((kernel, dict) => {
        dict["viewPath"] = "~";
        dict["layoutPath"] = "~";
        dict["runViewStartPages"] = true;
        dict["viewStartFileExtensions"] = new List<string>() { "cshtml"};
    })
```

I also didn't have Windsor cast RazorView as an IViewPageActivator since it does not implement that interface. If you read The post from [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt11-view-page-activator.html) your implementation of IDependencyResolver should return null for the IViewPageActivator if you don't have one.

Comment: Yes this works. I am also able to get the page to render if I leave out the IView and ControllerContext (and IViewPresenter as mentioned by Brad). So is it even necessary to put an implementation of a IView in the container?